# Does this common PDE have a name?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

What is the name of this common **2D** PDE:

$$\nabla^2 u - k^2 u=0$$

where $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

And where can I find a general solution and the way to derive it? THanks!

**Edit:**

Some people have suggested that this is the Helmoltz equation. My concern is the following: the Helmoltz equation does admit a solution with products of trigonometric functions and corresponding bessel J functions:

$$f(r,\phi)= A_n\sin(n\phi)J_n(\lambda r)$$

The one I wrote, with a minus instead of a plus, does not admit such solutions. Infact admits exponential solutions:

$$f(r,\phi)= \exp\left[\frac{\lambda}{\sqrt{2}} (r\cos\phi+r\sin\phi)\right]$$

because of its structure.

Comment: It is called the wave equation. Check the internet with this entry or try a physics book on electromagnetism or acoustics.

Comment: I can't find it in this form though, could you help me with that please? Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if you could indicate where this is coming from and what your definition of $\nabla^2$ is.  If defined as $\nabla^2 = \sum\partial^2_{x_ix_i}$, the Laplacian doesn't have any positive eigenvalues, so this equation isn't very useful.  If defined as $\nabla^2 = -\sum\partial^2_{x_ix_i}$, this is the Helmholtz equation.

Comment: Indeed, with the usual meaning of $∇{^2}$ there would only be the zero solution in an $L{^2}$ setting. I am more or less convinced that the equation is incorrectly copied. Please give a reference of where you encountered it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, I found out that this equation is a kind of modified Helmoltz equation. Solutions can be find by separation of variables (see Riley, Hobson, chapter 21), and they are:

$$f(r,\phi)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty I_n(k r)[A_n\cos(n\phi)+B_n\sin(n\phi)]$$

where $I_n(kr)$ is a modified Bessel function.

Answer (score 3):

*If* you define $\nabla^2$ as $\nabla^2 u = -\sum u_{x_ix_i}$, this is the Helmholtz equation.  If you then give it Dirichlet boundary conditions, it is the equation of [Dirichlet eigenvalues](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_eigenvalue), and it will have solutions.  If, however, you are defining $\nabla^2 u = \sum u_{x_ix_i}$, the Dirichlet problem for your equation (i.e. zero boundary condition) will have no nontrivial solutions by the spectral theorem, so it isn't very interesting.

Comment: I edited the equation to make my issue clearer.

Comment: You still don't give a domain or boundary conditions, without which there isn't much you can say about it.  As stated, on a bounded domain with either Dirichlet or Neumann BC's, your equation has only the trivial solution...

Comment: If your domain is $\Bbb{R}^2$, the exponential solution you give is unbounded for any $\lambda\in \Bbb{R}$ (along certain directions), so it would normally be rejected as a physical solution to anything.  I think one can prove that this equation can _only_ have unbounded solutions on $\Bbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score -1):

It is called [Helmotz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation). When derived from the wave equation, it appears with $+k^2\,u$ instead of $-k^2\,u$.

Comment: Doesnt' Helmoltz equation have a plus in front of $u$?

Comment: That is so when derived from the wave equation.

Comment: My concern is the following: the Helmoltz equation does admit a solution with products of trigonometric functions and corresponding bessel J functions. The one I wrote, with a minus instead of a plus, does not admit such solutions. Infact admits exponential solutions, because of its structure. Therefore, I cannot see how they are the same thing.

Comment: They are not the same thing. They have the same name. See for instance the entry for Helmholtz equation in [eqword](http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/lpde/lpde303.pdf).